# Replace text with linebreaks in a string that goes to a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, innerhtml, hta

I'm making a HTA-App for formating a long list of numbers to match the filter from Microsoft Dynamics AX.

The script gets the list from the clipboard and format it to paragraphs á 26 numbers and finaly print it to a textarea.

My problem: i don't know how to replace text with linebreaks for the paragraphs.

i tried `str.replace("text", "\r")` as well as `str.replace("text", "\n")` but it wont work.

It's maybe a bit complicated, but it works good and fast, exept the paragraphs..

here is the script:

```js
function start() {
  document.getElementById("dynamic").innerHTML = '<textarea id="to"></textarea>';
  document.getElementById("backbutton").innerHTML = '<img onClick="reset()" id="Back" src="src/back.png" alt="Zurück">';

  var cnt = 0;
  document.getElementById("to").innerHTML = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
  var to = document.getElementById("to").value;

  var num = to.search(" ");
  if (num > 0) {
    for (num = 1; num > 0; cnt++) {
      var num = to.search(" ");
      if (cnt > 26) {
        var to = to.replace(" ", "ABSATZ");
        var cnt = 0;
      } else {
        var to = to.replace(" ", "\,LEER");
      }
    }

    for (nex = 1; nex > 0;) {
      var nex = to.search("LEER");
      var to = to.replace("LEER", " ");
    }

    for (nex2 = 1; nex2 > 0;) {
      var nex2 = to.search("ABSATZ");
      var to = to.replace("ABSATZ", "PARAGRAPHS HERE");
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("to").innerHTML = to;
}
```

Comment: *"`to = to.replace(" ", "\,LEER");`"* `,` is not special in string literals, there's no need to escape it. If you wanted a backslash character there, you *do* need to escape that: `to = to.replace(" ", "\\,LEER");`

Comment: Where the text is copied to clipboard from? In a Windows text file the newline character is is usually `\r\n`, i.e. two characters. Splitting only by `\r` or `\n` leads unexpected results, especially if you're going to save the content into a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replace` with a string will only replace the first match. To replace all matches, you need to use a regular expression with the `g` flag:

```
str = str.replace(/text/g, "\n");
```

Be sure to escape any characters that are special in regular expressions.

---

You only need to declare a variable **once**. Putting `var` before every variable assignment in your code is both unnecessary and confusing.